# Scala Lift - Url re-write to pages within folder

Tags: scala, url-rewriting, lift

I have the following re-write rule:

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.prepend(NamedPF("AppRewrite") {

        case RewriteRequest(

            ParsePath(List("room", room, user), _, _, _), _, _) =>

                RewriteResponse(List("room"),

                    Map("room" -> room, "user" -> user)

                )

})
```

Which allows me to do

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/room/[room_id]/[user_id]
```

The html page that's loaded is in the webapp root (e.g webapp/room.html)

What I'm trying to do is add another parameter after room, so I can have

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/room/[page_id]/[room_id]/[user_id]
```

But instead of loading the room.html in the webapp root, it loads the page using the page_id in a sub folder called pages.

So I could have

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/room/join/[room_id]/[user_id]
```

Which would load

```
webapp/pages/room/join.html
```

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking how to rewrite `/room/join/[room_id]/[user_id]` to `/pages/room/join.html` then just follow the same URL rewriting pattern that you started with.

```
... // (in the same statlessRewrite.prepend block)
case RewriteRequest( 
  ParsePath( List("room", "join", roomId, userId), _, _, _), _, _) =>
    RewriteResponse(List("pages", "room", "join"), 
      Map("roomId" -> roomId, "userId" -> userId)
    )
```

You will also probably need to add "/pages/room/join.html" to your sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add a new case to your rewrite:

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.prepend(NamedPF("AppRewrite") {
        case RewriteRequest(
            ParsePath(List("room", room, user), _, _, _), _, _) =>
                RewriteResponse(List("room"),
                    Map("room" -> room, "user" -> user)
                )
        case RewriteRequest(
            ParsePath(List("room", page, room, user), _, _, _), _, _) =>
                RewriteResponse(List("pages", "room", page),
                    Map("room" -> room, "user" -> user)
                )
})
```